# Loading specific url breaks in webview

Tags: java, webview, javafx

When I load certain urls in my javafx webview application I get this error

```
Error 403
Guru Meditation:
XID: 1087555431
Varnish cache server
```

The website loads fine in Chrome, firefox, etc. It would appear that this is an issue with webview. What is a work around?

URL that breaks is http://mp3skull.com

Comment: The WebView is based on WebKit, but unless you give some more details on the error, it will be hard to give any advice.

Comment: It's not really an error with `WebView`, in the sense that webview is seemingly accurately showing the HTML it is receiving. My best guess (it's a guess) is that the web site is checking the user-agent request header and providing content based on that; because it doesn't recognize the header web view sets, it's just generating an HTML 403 error. (But that's a guess.)

Comment: you could be right. I did nothing more than initialize wbview = new WebView and run wbview.load("") to get this result. How do I set header information?

Comment: Which headers? Response headers you can see with `new URL("http://mp3skull.com/").openConnection().getHeaderFields().entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);` (as an ugly one-liner). Request headers that are sent... not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a fault of WebView, it is some kind of setting on the target site (as suggested by James_D in comments).  The target site is checking the user agent of the incoming request and responding with a weird [Amiga emulated guru meditation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru_Meditation) if it does not detect a recognized user agent.

To get around this, you can set the user agent of the WebView to masquerade as another browser (e.g. Chrome).  I copied a user agent from [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) and when I used the Chrome user agent string the target web page opened fine without any guru mediation.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Pirate extends Application {

    public static final String CHROME_41_USER_AGENT =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().setUserAgent(
                CHROME_41_USER_AGENT
        );
        webView.getEngine().load("http://mp3skull.com");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```